# What does #>> mean in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

What does the `#>>`  mean in the following sql statement?

```
full_spec#>>'{owner,sys}' LIKE '%Storage%'
```

It's in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

`full_spec#>>'{owner,sys}'`: This part uses the `#>>` operator, which is used to extract a value from a JSON object or JSON array. In this case, you are extracting the value of the owner and system properties into the JSON object stored in the full_spec field.

`LIKE '%Storage%'`: This is used to perform a text search on the string resulting from the extraction. In this case, the substring "Storage" is searched for in the extracted value.

Comment: fwiw, once you start needing to break open json data for use in predicates (WHERE, ON, etc), it's probably time to start extracting that data to their own fields at INSERT/UPDATE time instead, so you can index it. This can improve performance by multiple orders of magnitude.